# A temporary array is assigned but not a temporary primary value

Tags: c++, c++11, xvalue

I am amazed that this `C++` code is compiled:

```
int main()
{
    (int[10]){}[0]=15;
    return 0;
}
```

The equivalent assembly is

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-48], 0
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-40], 0
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-32], 0
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], 0
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], 0
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-48], 15
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

According to this code, an array is defined without having any name and then assigned.

Interestingly, when there is no array, the code does not compile:

```
int main()
{
    (int){}=15; /* <Compilation failed> */
    return 0;
}
```

1- Why is the first expression (maybe you call it assigning to an xvalue) legal in C++ for a temporary array but not the second one for a basic primary type? Why the language is designed this way?

2- What is the application of such a temporary array?

Comment: It compiles with [-fpermissive] flag with GCC. It gives a warning though.

Comment: `(int[10]){}` - Looks to me as a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) (a C thing, not a C++ thing). What did you compile with? And did you specify `-pednatic` or something equivalent?

Comment: Case and point: Clang and GCC reject it when made to emit pedantic errors https://godbolt.org/z/GjwJHj - If you wish to study the behavior of C++ code (without extension muddying the water), always add pedantic flags.

Comment: @StoryTeller without pedantic https://godbolt.org/z/I4C6l1

Comment: Thought so. You are looking at an extension, not something the C++ language specification prescribes.

Comment: @StoryTeller, So how is it fine at [this document](https://github.com/jeaye/value-category-cheatsheet/blob/master/value-category-cheatsheet.pdf) section X-values the last example?

Comment: @ar2015 - Ask the random author of this random document from the internet.

Comment: Though, they didn't use a compound literal in any example. An alias naming the type, and the type in parentheses are syntactically different things. Even before semantics are introduced. The code in your post and the one in the cheetsheet are not the same.

Comment: @StoryTeller, Their assembly are the same [here](https://godbolt.org/z/I4C6l1) and [there](https://godbolt.org/z/O3HBBw).  The blog of this guy comes [third](https://blog.jeaye.com/2017/03/19/xvalues/) when searching on google about c++ xvalues.

Comment: Then go ask him if you insist

Comment: @StoryTeller, No problem with that. But did not deserve a `-1`.

Comment: This actually looks like a bug in gcc, because it compiles this code even with gnu extensions disabled `--std=c++11`.

Comment: Your question sure did. Being based on a false premise, and not even showing standard C++ makes it not useful (and we are supposed to vote on what we consider not useful). I just decided to stop this back and forth and vote as I consider it, finally.

Comment: @VTT - `--std=c++11` by itself, does not disable all extensions. If it did, the world would be a happier place.

Comment: @StoryTeller, you see? We discovered a bug. We should not `-1` because of getting tired.

Comment: @ar2015 - It's not a bug. No matter how much wishful thinking you throw at it.